# How to compare elements of a list of lists (Python)

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

```
identical = 0
while x < len(BigList):
    while y < len(BigList):
        if BigList[x][0] == BigList[y][0] and y != x:
            identical += 1
        y += 1
    x += 1
```

How can I properly see if the `0th` element of every list in big list is equal to another 0th element in another list in Big List?

i.e., I need `[[1,2],[2,3],[1,4],[2,5]]` to make `identical=2` because 2 lists have their 0th element equal to another list's `0th` element

tia

Comment: In the example, all 4 lists have their 0th element equal to another list's 0th element.

Answer (score 6):

```
identical = len(BigList) - len(set(item[0] for item in BigList))
```

The number of duplicates = The number of items in BigList minus the number of unique zeroth index items

Answer (score 2):

first make a list of the 0th elements ... then count occurances (if you are 2.7+ you can use collections.Counter on your zeroth list

```
zeros = [mylist[0] for mylist in biglist]
my_dict = dict([(c,zeros.count(c)) for c in zeros])
dup_elems = filter(lambda key:my_dict[key]>1, my_dict.keys())
print len(dup_elems)
```

Comment: +1, I was about to post the exact same answer. BTW `for c in set(zeros)`, would be better.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yeah thats a good point but meh ... doubt it will make much of a human timescale difference (and depending the `set` cast may take any savings away)
@user1713330 meh not as good as Ashwini :P

Comment: I'm now trying to use counter integers for your code that count the amount of times a certain element occurs

Comment: @user1713330 Is there a problem you are encountering? or just sayin?  (edited slightly to better reflect what I think you want)

Comment: @JoranBeasley It could make a difference if there are large number of same values in `zeros`. And how about `collections.Counter(zeros)`

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yeah I mentioned that... but i run 2.6 so afaik thats out for me

Answer (score 0):

1. Count the number of sublists that share the element at index 0.
2. Count the number of identical sublists.
3. The difference between the two is what you are after.

Code:

```
firstElems = zip(*L)[0]
firstSames = sum(v for v in collections.Counter(firstElems).values if v != 1)
equals = sum(v for v in collections.counter(tuple(l) for l in L).values if v!=1)
answer = firstSames - equals
```

Hope this helps.